# Spring Security with Java Config - GET mehods allowed / POST methods denied (403) without any apparent reason

Tags: java, spring, security, post, config

For my Spring web application, I opted for a full Java Config, no XML here !

The application run generally well, but I a have little problem that I can't elucidate.

All my secured GET methods are allowed, and all my POST methods are denied.

For example, I a have a JSP with a form below.
If I use a POST method, I'm redirect to 403 page error. And if I use GET method, I pass in my method "validateCreateStep1" without any problem...

So I would like allow any type of method in my secured area, not only GET !

Someone would have an idea ?

Thx with advance & take a look to the code below ;)

**SpringConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @Bean @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
            throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
            throws Exception {

        auth
            .userDetailsService(loginService)
            .passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) 
            throws Exception {

        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/signup", 
                        "/signup/do",
                        "/static/**"
                );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) 
            throws Exception {

        http
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll() 
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()

            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .failureUrl("/?err=1")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()

            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/?out=1")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()

            .sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/?time=1")
                .maximumSessions(1);
    }

}
```

**EventController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/event")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/create/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String prepareCreate(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("eventForm", new EventForm());

        return "eventCreate";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/create/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateCreate(ModelMap model, @Valid @ModelAttribute(value="eventForm") EventForm form, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {

        String redirect = null;

        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            EventEntity event = eventService.create();
            redirect = "dashboard";
        } else {
            redirect = "eventCreate";
        }

        return redirect;
    }
}
```

**event-create.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<div>
    <h3>
        <spring:message code="event.create.title" />
    </h3>
    <div>
        <c:url value="/event/create/validate" var="formActionURL" />
        <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="eventForm" action="${formActionURL}">
            <form:label path="firstname">
                <spring:message code="event.create.firstname.label" />
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="firstname" />
            <form:errors path="firstname" cssClass="formFieldError" />
            <br />
            <form:label path="lastname">
                <spring:message code="event.create.lastname.label" />
            </form:label>
            <form:input path="lastname" />
            <form:errors path="lastname" cssClass="formFieldError" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="event.create.submit.label" />" />
        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that if I disable CSRF token, the problem disappear.

```
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll() 
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
```

So in that case, POST methods are successfully. But if I well understand, CSRF token disabling is less secured no ?
And I can't enable it only for login for example.

Comment: include CSRF token in your form: <input type="hidden"
    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>

Comment: mmm... oops. when you using <form:form> tag, csrf token mus be automatically included by Spring MVC. Inspect the generated html form for _csrf token existance. If you see <input> tag with name "_csrf" and no value, maybe you have to turn on a session. Anyway, make attention to response body when you get 403 error, it may explain the situation

Comment: With CSRF activated or not, hidden CSRF tag is never automatically generated in my <form: form>. =/ For login, I had already been forced to add it by myself. Have I missed an option ? It would be very uncomfortable if I need to put it by myself in each form that I create...

Comment: which version of spring security r u using

Comment: Spring version 4.1.7.RELEASE and Spring Security version 3.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: Nobody for a magic idea ?! :)

Answer (score 1):

In Angular2 [HttpClientXsrfModule module](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientXsrfModule) is responsible for that.

There is a really helpful comment in the code of [Interceptor implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.8/packages/common/http/src/xsrf.ts#L77):

> ```
> // Skip both non-mutating requests and absolute URLs.
> // Non-mutating requests don't require a token, and absolute URLs require special handling
> // anyway as the cookie set
> // on our origin is not the same as the token expected by another origin.
> if (req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'HEAD' || lcUrl.startsWith('http://') ||
>     lcUrl.startsWith('https://')) {
>   return next.handle(req);
> }
> ```

Sometimes, it explains ;)